# How do I complete or skip the tutorial on tiny death star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I just started playing the game on my dell windows 8 and have four floors, one of which is residential. My latest mission is to build a new residential floor, but when I try to, it says "access denied, you need to finish the tutorial". did I do something out of order? or is it a bug? or what do I need to do to finish the tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial can be skipped on the emperor page but you have to pay some `bux`. If it's a bug you can easily restart the whole game and try to see if it's fixed.